# How to override top menu and add icon in Magento 2?

Tags: overrides, topmenu, magento2.4.1, icon

How to override top menu and add icon in Magento 2?

I'm using Magento v2 and want to have icons added to each category menu item.?
How can I override this?

**I added the Attribute for icon in category (Admin)**

I need like this

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Content of Menu is coming from  Block Classes

- `\Magento\Catalog\Plugin\Block\Topmenu`
- `\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu`

HTMl is created at `\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu::_getHtml` and `\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu::_addSubMenu` and I think for your requirement you need to override these classes using preference and do what you want.

Comment: i need icon add in the menu (like image)